# How can I get a git submodule's associated commit ID from a past commit in the parent clone?

Tags: git, diff, git-submodules

Is there a way, short of actually checking out the parent commit, to determine a submodule's SHA-1 commit ID based on a commit ID in the parent clone? I know I can find the *currently* associated SHA-1 with `git submodule`.

Here's an example:

- I have a clone with a single submodule `foo` that has changed several times in the last month.
- I have a tag in the parent clone that is a few weeks old called `released-1.2.3`. I want to find out what the associated SHA-1 of `foo` was for this tagged commit.
- I could simply check out `released-1.2.3` and use `git submodule` to see, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this *without* affecting the working tree, as I want to script it.

I want to do this because I want to construct a script to do a 'diff' on all changes within a submodule between two commits within the parent repository - i.e. "tell me what files changed within the submodule `foo` between these two commits in the parent."

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You may use [`git-ls-tree`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-tree.html) to see what the SHA-1 id of a given path was during a given commit:

```
$ git ls-tree released-1.2.3 foo
160000 commit c0f065504bb0e8cfa2b107e975bb9dc5a34b0398  foo
```

(My first thought was `git show released-1.2.3 foo`, but that fails with "fatal: bad object".)

Since you are scripting the output, you will probably want to get just the SHA-1 id by itself, e.g.:

```
$ git ls-tree released-1.2.3 foo | awk '{print $3}'
c0f065504bb0e8cfa2b107e975bb9dc5a34b0398
```

Also: When writing scripts around git, try to stick to the [plumbing](http://git-scm.com/docs/git#_low_level_commands_plumbing) commands, as described in the manual. They have a more stable interface, while the more familiar “porcelain” commands will possibly change in incompatible ways.

Comment: I think this is the answer I'm looking for - this does seem to return the hash of the submodule for the specified parent commit. Thank you. Also, plumbing comment noted - thanks.

Comment: To discover submodules with their hashes at arbitrary commit: `git ls-tree --full-tree -r commit|grep ^160000`. The grep is for the mode used for submodule links.

Comment: @S.ChristofferEliesen, add -r to find all submodules, not only those in ./

Comment: @JoshLee Care to explain what you mean when you say that scripting with `git` should generally be restricted to plumbing commands? Clearly, these are a subset of everything one can tell git to do, but why are they preferable for this purpose?

Comment: I don't understand, what is foo ? What is released-1.2.3 ?

Answer (score 7):

This one worked for me:

```
$ git rev-parse released-1.2.3^{commit}:foo
<SHA1>
```

Perhaps also quite easy to use in script.

Comment: I was surprised to see that `rev-parse` understood the submodule.

Comment: I think you don't need to explicitly deref the reference with `^{commit}`, just use plain `<commit-ish>:<submodule-path>`. Other than that that's a great answer

Answer (score 2):

I did find one promising avenue:

```
$ git log --raw <since>..<until> --submodule -- <path/to/submodule>
```

With the --raw option, this does print out the (abbreviated) SHA-1 IDs corresponding to the submodule's associated commits. Unfortunately the output is very verbose and will take some work to process in a script.

What I really need is a git facility that, given a parent commit ID, gives me the latest change to a submodule prior to that commit. I.e. which submodule SHA-1 'git submodule update' would check out if I were to actually checkout that parent commit.

Comment: git log --format=%H will get you hashes.. so will git rev-parse

Comment: Thanks for your comments, adymitruk. However --format=%H and rev-parse return the hashes for the parent clone's commit, not the actual hash of the submodule, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

git slave (gits) might be your answer.

http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/

But you can also do this with plain git..  it's not as easy.

Answer (score 0):

`git` `ls-tree` will do the job.
But sometimes you should call it several times or use `-r` to show subentries recursively.

```
    ├─project
    │  └─submodules
    │      ├─submodule_a
    │      ├─submodule_b
    │      ├─...
```

For example, if you has such a project directory, and you want the commit id of `submodule_a` with an tag name in parent module.

```
git ls-tree v5.4.0
```

will give you the tree id of directory `submodules`, not commit id. It looks like as following.

```
040000 tree e542bc1b084a0394ff16452c27df6572366e0009    submodules
```

Just feed `ls-tree` with the tree id, and you will get the actual commit id of each submodule.

```
git ls-tree e542bc
```

You will get something like this.

```
160000 commit 0f253bf94e0345600cb7a234a24eeec8ee3533bd  submodule_a
160000 commit 0edcbaf94e034987cb4eeec8ee3533bd12349ade  submodule_b
```

Or just use

```
git ls-tree v5.4.0 -r
```

to check all entries tree id or commit id.