# A git submodule is stuck at wrong commit ('submodule update' doesn't work)

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a parent project with a submodule (no nested submodules). The submodule has a new commit (let's call it `new-sha`), and the parent refers to that commit in remote repo (I can see `submodule @ new-sha` when viewing the repo in web browser). 
I have pulled the parent project, and it also refers to the right commit in the working directory, as seen in `git show` output:

```
--- a/submodule
--- b/submodule
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit old-sha
+Subproject commit new-sha
```

I.e. the latest commit in parent project has changed the submodule to `new-sha`. However, neither `git submodule update` nor `git pull --recurse-submodules` update to `new-sha` in the submodule, they always check out `old-sha`.

Why, and how to fix it?

git version 2.21.0.windows.1

Some additional information: the submodule has `sha-new` locally, but its HEAD is stuck at `sha-old`.

`sha-new` is immediately derived from `sha-old`, and here are the last 3 commits, maybe this can give a clue:

```
sha-new  == the top of submodule's branch used by parent project
sha-old  == HEAD
sha-xyz  == origin/HEAD
```

The `origin/HEAD` line worries me. Even after manually pulling the submodule (`cd submodule; git pull origin branch-name:branch-name`) `origin/HEAD` stayed at third commit from top.

Comment: Even after manually pulling the submodule: can you the do a `cd ..; git add submodule`  (no trailing slash, replace 'submodule' by the name of the root folder of that submodule), and check again?

Comment: I "solved" it differently. I had to do some changes in the submodule, so I manually switched to the right commit, did and committed the changes in submodule, and committed the submodule in the parent project. This finally updated the reference to submodule.

Comment: If this happens again in the future, I will try your advice and will comment here. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I have edited the answer according to your comment, with an explanation.

Comment: So, it happened again yesterday. _git submodule add_ didn't work immediately, but then I found [this discussion](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/SourceTree-says-No-url-found-for-submodule-path/qaq-p/628869) where the person had (apparently conflicting) version of submodule in the index (_git ls-files --stage | grep 160000_). After removing it from index (_git rm --cached_) and re-adding it with _git submodule add_ I was finally able to update the submodule from the parent project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the new commit was pushed to the submodule remote repository. (the one listed in the [`.gitmodules` URL line](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules#Documentation/gitmodules.txt-submoduleltnamegturl))

Then you need to do a git status within your main parent repo local clone, to check it is at the latest of the `master` branch and that [`git ls-tree` does show the right submodule root tree commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5033973/6309).

---

The [OP me76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6580788/me76) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371564/a-git-submodule-is-stuck-at-wrong-commit-submodule-update-doesnt-work#comment99436148_56371564):

> I "solved" it differently.
> I had to do some changes in the submodule, so I manually switched to the right commit, did and committed the changes in submodule, and committed the submodule in the parent project.
> This finally updated the reference to submodule.

That is because doing so forces the main repository to update the [**gitlink** (special entry in the index)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/1.8.3#_description) to reference the new commit of the submodule main folder tree.
Pushing that will publish that new gitlink commit.

---

The OP also refers to [this thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/SourceTree-says-No-url-found-for-submodule-path/qaq-p/628869):

> The person had (apparently conflicting) version of submodule in the index (`git ls-files --stage | grep 160000`).
>
> After removing it from index (`git rm --cached`) and re-adding it with `git submodule add`, I was finally able to update the submodule from the parent project.

Note: the `git rm --cached asubmoduleFolder` must not ends with '`/`': you are removing a gitlink (the '160000' special entry in the index). Not a folder.

Comment: The submodule commit `sha-new` is in the remote; the parent project is at the latest commit (that refers to submodule's `sha-new`); and `git ls-tree current-parent-branch` shows `160000 commit new-sha submodule`.

Comment: I've added some details regarding submodule's history.

Comment: @me76 OK, I have included your comment (with a note of mine) in the answer.