# Why do am i getting error 404 on my sub module symlink found on my git repo?

Tags: windows, git, git-submodules, symlink, hugo

I'm currently having an issue with my git submodule. I've created a git submodule in my cloned project folder and it appears right on my repo. But when I click on the symlink, it gives me Error 404 page not found. I am VS Code and Windows 8 x64. Thanks a lot for your help! Below is what is written in the .gitmodules

```
[submodule "themes/casper-two"]
    path = themes/casper-two
    url = "https://github.com/eueung/hugo-casper-two"
```

[image: submodule symlink]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find the `caa182b` commit in the [hugo-casper-two](https://github.com/eueung/hugo-casper-two) repository, so I believe you need to update the submodule to the latest commit available. To do this, run the following command from your project directory:

```
git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```

This command will update every submodule in your project and pull the latest commit from their master branch.

Remember to commit your own repository afterwards.

```
git commit -am "Pulled down updates to submodules"
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help! So I ran the first command: git submodule foreach git pull origin master and it returns : Entering 'themes/casper-two'
From https://github.com/eueung/hugo-casper-two
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.

Comment: If it still does not work, you may want to try the suggestions [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371564/a-git-submodule-is-stuck-at-wrong-commit-submodule-update-doesnt-work). If this does not work either, I would [completely remove the submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule) and add it back.