# How does git handle cloning another repository into a subdirectory?

Tags: git, git-submodules, subdirectory

I just cloned a repository into a subdirectory of another repository, and git actually appeared to handle the situation pretty intelligently.  I know about submodules, but I thought they always had to be explicitly defined and I didn't think git had this functionality.  What happened?

Here's my shell session:

https://gist.github.com/858131

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It handles it as a **nested repository**, not as a submodule.
As you found out, to declare it as a submodule:

- the sub-directory shouldn't already exist, meaning if you already cloned your second repo, you need to delete it first before adding it as a submodule.
- or you can try adding it directly in the `.gitmodules` file (not tested)

That will allow for the creation of the [special entry in the git index referencing the submodule SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992018/git-submodule-update-needed-only-initially/2227598#2227598), as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983829/how-can-i-get-a-git-submodules-associated-commit-id-from-a-past-commit-in-the-pa/4010165#4010165), and detailed in the SO question "[Nested git repositories without submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317652/nested-git-repositories-without-submodules/2317870#2317870)".

Answer (score 2):

The second repository is being handled as a submodule by the first repository. Since you haven't defined it as a submodule though, you can not interact with it using the `git submodule` command, but all other commands treat it as a submodule.

Comment: OK... now that I've gotten my repository into this state, how can I tell `git submodule` to treat the second repository as a submodule?

Comment: @jnylen: `git submodule add git://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish.git bundle/vim-abolish`

Comment: That (just adding the submodule normally) only worked after I blew away what was already there.  Good enough though, thanks.

Comment: @jnylen: I think you might've been able to get away with manually adding it to `.gitmodules`, too.