# Checkout in git superproject and submodules

Tags: git

Consider a superproject with a submodule. If the superproject is checked out to a previous commit, how to automatically check out the submodule to the corresponding commit ?

Superproject : A - B

Submodule : X - Y - Z

Superproject HEAD is on B, corresponding index on submodule is on Z. Imagine that in A, submodule index was in X. How can I automatically checkout submodule on X when I check out superproject in A ?

I can do it manually thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983829/how-can-i-get-a-git-submodules-associated-commit-id-from-a-past-commit-in-the-p) but it is not efficient for superproject with many submodules.

[Edit] By checkout, I mean using `git checkout commitSHA1`. 
According to the [doc](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html),

> Prepare to work on top of , by detaching HEAD at it (see
>   "DETACHED HEAD" section), and updating the index and the files in the
>   working tree.

I want to recompile code as it was in superproject commit A (possibly tagged) without knowing explicitly corresponding submodules indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the command you're looking for is:

```
git submodule update
```

That should get all your submodules to the right version (when run after your `git checkout`)

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule